# Why isn't inline JavaScript code being executed in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openlayers

This is my complete View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { layers: 'basic' });
    map.addLayer(wms);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

</script>
```

But when I run it nothing I can't see the map.

I made a HTML page in Notepad that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
      <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And it works.

Why isn't the code being executed in ASP.NET?

I installed OpenLayers from NuGet and if I select OpenLayers and press F12 ('Go To Definition' it opens up OpenLayers.js so it seems to have been downloaded correctly).

**EDIT**:
The complete generated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FIKA - Home</title>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/css?v=bxomq82-FU9mU3eDX6m-kca-a2PFEz0RK2Z7mS-QmnY1" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">



<div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
    var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { layers: 'basic' });
    map.addLayer(wms);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();

</script>
        <hr />
    </div>

    <script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>

    <script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"0ea737fab0f240fab62a7978c5db4fa7"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:60314/4457514eae394a96a55c4c6c386b7942/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the complete generated code you include the `http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js` script twice. Maybe that is what causing your issue.

Comment: Hi, there was another guy suggesting (now deleted) that I added that script tag into the view but I tried adding it into both the View (only), the header in the Layout (only) and also both but none of those changes worked.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: Checking the browser's console I don't see any error. Also it works using the same code in a HTML page created in Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue occurs because in the complete generated code you have the HTML5 doctype where in your working demo you do not have a doctype. That difference occurs for the browser to render differently the `height:100%;` property.

You need to set the height in pixels before executing your code.

```
function setMapHeight() {
    var w = window,
    d = document,
    e = d.documentElement,
    g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    document.getElementById('map').style.height = (w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight) + 'px';
}

setMapHeight();
window.onresize = setMapHeight; // Add this code to fix height if window resizes

var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", { layers: 'basic' });
map.addLayer(wms);
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

Comment: Thanks Tasos, it works great. I imagined it was something like this but couldn't figure out what it was, once again thanks!